# OpenGL rendering on RDP

Tags: c++, opengl, rdp

I have an application which uses OpenGL in a fairly simple way to render textured QUADS.

It's working fine when running locally, but when running remotely (Microsoft Remote Desktop) it displays blank white windows.

I was wondering if some of the configurations I've made are a direct reason for that, or is it something more fundamental that can only be solved by another approach, like using [Display Lists](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter07.html) or something like that.

My code follows. I initialize the contexts like this:

```
void InitWindow(HWND *hWnd, HDC *hDC, HGLRC *hRC)
{
    *hDC = GetDC(*hWnd);

    // set the pixel format for the DC
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | 
            PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;

    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    //      pfd.cRedBits = 8;   
    //      pfd.cGreenBits = 8;
    //      pfd.cBlueBits = 8;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 0;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 0;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int format = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, format, &pfd);

    // create and enable the render context (RC)
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    // make current context current 
    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}
```

And draw to the screen like this:

```
int Render(HWND hWnd, Raster* raster)
{
    Size RasterSize = raster->GetSize();

    HDC hDC = NULL;
    HGLRC hRC = NULL;

    // acquire DC, HGLRC for the window & make current
    InitWindow(&hWnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    GLenum raster_pixel_format = GL_BGRA_EXT;
    GLint internal_format = GL_RGBA;

    if (s_ClearBeforeDraw)
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    GLuint texture;
    // allocate a texture name
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format, 
            RasterSize.width, RasterSize.height,
            0, raster_pixel_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            raster->GetData());

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    RECT wndRect;
    ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &wndRect);
    GLsizei wndWidth = wndRect.right;
    GLsizei wndHeight = wndRect.bottom;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // this is usually stated in window coordinates,
    // but since we know the raster gets its size from 
    // the window - we can use raster coordinates
    glViewport(0, 0, RasterSize.width, RasterSize.height);

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );    

    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

    SwapBuffers(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

    // Release the context handles if they aren't cached
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It seems this is supposed to work (slowly), but will depend if you started your app before connecting via RDP or after. When started after, opengl doesn't detect 3D acceleration.

Comment: @Eugene: That's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL detects nothing because OpenGL is not some kind of library. It's part of the GPU's driver and in RDP mode there's no GPU support.

Comment: @datenwolf Well, wglCreateContext() likely returns NULL, that's why OP sees white window. If the app is started before RDP is connected, context would be created already. (detection! :)) At least according to this report: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c8295ef8-3711-4576-9293-2c4965280165/opengl-and-remote-desktop

Comment: @Eugene: Yes I do understand that. But this is not detection, but simply due to the fact that when you start a program from RDP it will run using a different graphics driver. In the case of RDP a driver that lacks OpenGL support. Again, OpenGL detects nothing, because there is not **the** OpenGL. There's just **a** OpenGL implementation available or not.

Comment: I'm gonna have to test the "starting the program before connecting to the machine via RDP". However, that's not a viable solution for me.
I'm thinking about a primitive GDI+ fall-back. Isn't there a way to adjust my current code to run on "software acceleration" when RDP is detected at run-time, without using additional libraries?

Comment: The (standard) OpenGL implementation in RDP has a rather limited maximum texture size, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RDP you normally don't have GPU acceleration. I suggest you get yourself a Windows build of the MesaGL software rasterizer and depending on if you're on a RDP connection set the PATH environment variable to make it find that alternative opengl32.dll so that you have a nice software renderer.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to get Microsoft's OpenGL context (2.x only) in an RDP session, at least on newer versions of Windows.  I had an application fail when I tried to run over RDP, but the problem was with VBOs, not OpenGL basics.  After providing a fallback path to use client-side addresses for vertex arrays when VBO creation failed, it started working fine again.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, yes, client side vertex arrays have been part of OpenGL-1.1, which is in fact the version the software fallback of Windows provides. So if you're using RDP you don't get GPU acceleration, but a fallback to the slow software implementation (at least that one is conforming to OpenGL-1.1, but nothing more – no extensions, no nothing)

Comment: So what's the advantage of installing MesaGL, per your answer?  Your comments on the question sure implied that NO implementation of OpenGL is available.

Comment: @BenVoigt: With Mesa you get OpenGL-3.3 support, implemented by the `softpipe` renderer. Also I didn't write that there was NO OpenGL implementation, there's just no GPU acceleration, which is a huge difference (read my answer again, no edits done, it's always been written that way).

Comment: It was definitely the comments above, things like "when you start a program from RDP it will run using a different graphics driver. In the case of RDP a driver that lacks OpenGL support."  It doesn't specifically say "you cannot initialize OpenGL" but strongly implies that.  More correct would be "a driver that lacks hardware acceleration".  Also, when using a software fallback, most applications would want to simplify rendering.  It may be that modern OpenGL is best even with software rendering, but you definitely don't want to hide the lack of acceleration from the app.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, "the driver lacking OpenGL support" (specifically it lacks a OpenGL ICD) is *exactly* the right thing to write, because, that's the situation. Without a OpenGL capable graphics driver, the Windows GDI falls back to the software OpenGL-1.1 implementation; however that happens not in the driver but in the GDI user space DLLs.